# How to prevent Spring Boot from using unwanted HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Let's assume I have Spring Boot application that exposes HTTP API and talks to some external services over HTTP. I need to configure different HttpMessageConverter for each endpoint - one for our API entry point and one for each external service. All of them are instances of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

It's easy to achieve. For instance we can define global bean of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter that is added by Spring to HttpMessageConverters, and nested beans (also instances of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) used and visible only to RestClients.

My question is how to prevent developers from adding by mistake new globally visible bean that will by automatically added to HttpMessageConverters and may be used instead of the expected one?

The simplest solution that came to my mind would adding such test:

```
   @Test
   public void shouldBeOnlyOneInstanceOfHttpMessageConverter() { 
     assertThat(applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class)).hasSize(1);
   }
```

It should work, but it looks a little bit tricky. Is there any way of forcing Spring Boot to use explicitly defined converter?